# when valuing derivatives, we take into account the CSA. question is, should settlement currency also impact?

Tags: currency, settlement

eg supposing i have a payoff of 100 GBP on 5/5/2025.
and my CSA is USD SOFR.

and supposing i have another identical derivative, except it's payoff is 100 * GBPUSD spot (in USD) at 5/5/2025
or that its payoff is 100 * GBPEUR spot  (in euros) at that date.

so the only difference between all 3 of these is the settlement currency.
then should all these 3 have exactly the same value?

i am guessing the answer is yes.
and the only scenario where the choice of settlement currency may have impact is if the CSA allowed choice of which currency to use - ie a CTD CSA.

Comment: Arbitrage-free pricing theory tells you that the CSA (and specifically the corresponding Price Alignment Interest mechanism) determines the "risk-free" rate you should use to discount future cash flows. So you are right, the settlement currency will not matter here: the payoff stays 100 GBP and the discounting is USD SOFR. For a CTD CSA, again the payoff doesn't change, but the "discounting" should now incorporate the CTD feature. The fair value of the deal is then usually expressed as its "risk-free" MtM (without the CTD feature) + some xVA (accounting for the CTD feature).

Comment: REM: in all above cases the price in GBP should be $$V_0 = 100 P^{USD}(0,T) FX^{GBPUSD}(0,T)/FX^{GBPUSD}(0)$$ where $P^{USD}$ denotes the USD SOFR curve and $FX^{GBPUSD}(0,T)$ the GBP-USD FX-forward curve, which is usually expressed as $$FX^{GBPUSD}(0,T)=FX^{GBPUSD}(0)*P^{GBP\_CSA\_USD}(0,T)/P^{USD}(0,T)$$ so that at the end of the day the price of GBP$$V_0 = 100 P^{GBP\_CSA\_USD}(0,T)$$contrary to the standard $$V_0 = 100 P^{GBP\_CSA\_GBP}(0,T) = 100 P^{GBP}(0,T)$$